# Download table as image r

Tags: r, shiny

I want to be able to download a table as an image(PNG or JPEG). Let's assume that my dataframe is df

```
output$statsTable <- renderTable({
    #Printing the table
    df
})

output$downloadStatsTable <- downloadHunter(
    filename = function() {
        paste(getwd(), '/test.png', sep = '')
    },

    content = function(con) {
        p <- grid.table(df)
        device <- function(..., width, height) grDevices::png(..., width = 12, height = 9, res = 300, units = "in")
        ggsave(file, plot = p, device = device)
    }
)
```

Comment: What is your issue? Is your code not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: The issue is I have a button which when clicked will download an image of the table and I don't know how to do it. The code above will not work as there's no plot to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download table as image you can use grid.table function from library `gridExtra`. Here is a code which you could use as a template:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(shiny)


df <- head(datasets::iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("statsTable"),
  downloadButton('downloadStatsTable ', 'Download')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
output$statsTable <- renderTable({
  #Printing the table
  df
})


output$downloadStatsTable  <- downloadHandler(
  # Create the download file name
  filename = function() {
    paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".jpeg", sep="")
  },
  content = function(file) {
    grid.table(df)
    jpeg(file=file) 
    grid.table(df) #Create image of the data frame
    dev.off()
  })      

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Hope it helps!